# Magento 2 custom template and ReactJS

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

Does anyone have experience using ReactJS when making a custom Magento template? Or does anyone know if it is viable?

I would like to leverage ReactJS to make a single-page website.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Magento two has 2 JS templating libraries included in core, underscore.js and knockout.js. Why do you need react?

Comment: Most of the team is experienced with React and React Native so they would like to use those resources

Comment: Just because Magento use it it doesn't mean it's the best choice, React is much better than KO in many areas (performance, community etc.)

Comment: @Josh The problem with the M2 iJS stack is that it's horribly outdated.

Comment: Totally agree, the frontend architecture in M2 is very outdated. Don't blame you for wanting to layer in React.

But I'd consider the time investment in doing so. If you are trying to accomplish something small it may not be worth the time investment when the same features can be accomplished with native M2 JS processes

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet for this will be to use the [Rest API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/bk-rest.html). In this way you can have a completely separate frontend with server rendered pages (read: node) and single page app etc.

I'm surprised there isn't a popular github for such a project by now!

Comment: There is one gaining some traction although it isn't finished yet and isn't open source from what I can remember - https://www.front-commerce.com/

Comment: The architecture seems a bit strange, but the demo looks promising, very fast.

Comment: Yeah I was really impressed with the speed, will be interesting to see it in the wild and check if it's still as fast.

Comment: At least M2 has a strong API, it could be their saving grace.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, popular projects for custom JS-based view tend to use Vue.js instead of ReactJS

Comment: I feel like React is still in the driver's seat in terms of popularity, but things change quickly in the JS community. Either way a Vue-based UI would be way better than the Knockout / jQuery mess they have going in the stock M2 setup!